# QGIS Field Calculator Syntax Error Problem

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, syntax, syntaxerror

I never before worked with the field calculator and this problem is driving me nuts ...

[image: This is the error I get with my expression]

Interpretationserror:
syntax error, unexpected NAME
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end

```
My expression is: ((“crimes_2020” - ("crimes_2017_2019” / 3)) / ("crimes_2017_2019” / 3)) * 100
```

Also, the <kbd>Ok</kbd> Button always seems to be greyed out.

Comment: At least you are using some characters which look like double quotes but actually they are something else. Look at the both sides of `crimes_2020` for example.

Comment: Wow such a simple mistake. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was pointed by @user30184, you shall use a straight double quote [`"`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) instead of the one that you used [`“`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)/[`”`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) (opening/closing double quote).

So your expression will look like this:

```
(("crimes_2020" - ("crimes_2017_2019" / 3)) / ("crimes_2017_2019" / 3)) * 100
```

---

**References:**

- [FileFormat.Info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm)
- [Are there different types of double quotes in utf-8 (PHP, str_replace)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735921/are-there-different-types-of-double-quotes-in-utf-8-php-str-replace)
- [straight and curly quotes](https://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer ! Have a nice day!